# Query Feature using OpenLayers + MapServer

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver, query

I'm trying to query a feature in OpenLayers, but it's returning just an image highlighted that is not possible to make zoom, pan and drag.

My intention is to query a feature on the map like street name, city and country. Is there any function in OpenLayers?

I'm using this code:

```
var query = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Utbs", 
    "http://localhost/cgi-bin/wms.exe", 
    {
    srs: 'EPSG:4326',
    width: '800',
    styles: '',
    height: '600',
    layers: 'layer_name',   
    mode: 'itemquerymap',
    qstring: "(value = '03')",
    qlayer: 'layer_name',
    mapxy: 'shape'  
    },
    {
    singleTile: true    
    }
);

map.addLayers([utbs_query]);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Feature Info example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html) for OpenLayers.

This uses the GetFeatureInfo requests for WMS layers to return attribute data. You may have to modify your WMS configuration in MapServer or GeoServer (or whatever is serving your WMS layers) to support this.

Comment: Actually a want to highlight and make a zoom in a feature that was typed in a field name. The method GetFeatureInfo just return information about this feature where you clicked hover, so this is not what i want to.

Thanks!

Comment: The GetFeatureInfo requests can also return the geometry of a feature. With this you can zoom/highlight.

Comment: But i need to query by the name of a feature, not by a event click, is it possible?

Comment: You could try building a GeoExt search form to query your WMS or WFS http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/search-form.html