# Identifying using mapserver

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, postgresql, mapserver

I am just creating a simple web application using mapserver. It has the basic pan, zoom in/out functionality. Now what I want to try is to get an identify functional added into it so that when I click on a feature it populates the values in a table or a pop up.

Apart from using OpenLayers could anyone tell me how can this be implemented?

The data is coming from PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

A very similar question has already been answered here: [Query Feature using OpenLayers + MapServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11619/query-feature-using-openlayers-mapserver)

There's also a thread on the mapserver-users mailing list which starts with this post - http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2009-October/063369.html